# How can I allow multiple logins with forms authentication?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I have a problem with membership authentication. I have two websites, website1 and website2, and both of them uses forms authentication with SQL membership provider (SQLEXPRESS). I have two scenarios:

#### Case 1:

don't publish the website1 and try to login website1 with user1 -->Works ok
don't publish the website2 and try to login --> it displays the previously logged in user (Website1 user)-->Perfect

#### Case 2:

publish the website1 and login-->works ok
publish the website2 and try to login--> it does not show up the site1's logged in user (No idea why)

then login into website2 and open website1-->it does not show up the website2 logged in user or any user...

It looks like something wrong with cookies....

my web.config looks like this:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/LogOn/LogOn" timeout="2880" protection="All"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

Please let me if you have any ideas on this...

thanks,
swetha

Answer (score 1):

you need to establish the same machineKey for each website. generate one [here](http://www.developmentnow.com/articles/machinekey_generator.aspx)

and place this element in both web.config and see how it goes.

also, the application names must be the same. see [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/22/Always-set-the-_2200_applicationName_2200_-property-when-configuring-ASP.NET-2.0-Membership-and-other-Providers.aspx)

**also** you may want to enable [enableCrossAppRedirects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61.aspx)

```
...
<system.web>
  ...
  <machineKey 
validationKey="36DFB653C93BE95D70071E2033069338CC8AB908B75639BDEACE846838D9455B7926BA0C50CFDD4F8361643C200913244C3DBC14482895FC05B5CE6B8F24F2A2"
decryptionKey="AC737C3E32A594AB50EF38C3BB40537A4794F2E638D859898368BD1B35A5FF81"
validation="SHA1" decryption="AES"
/>

  ...
</system.web>
...
```

Comment: Thanks Skysander!! but i tried those settings...my web.config in both websites looks like this.. <authentication mode="Forms"> <forms loginUrl="~/Login/Login" timeout="2880" enableCrossAppRedirects="true"/> </authentication> <membership> <providers> <clear/> <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" ...

Comment: ... passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" applicationName="App1"/>
        </providers>
    </membership>
<authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="~/LogOn/LogOn" timeout="2880" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" />
        </authentication>

Comment: when i did include the machine key it works for single user.like both websites works fine for the same user. but i can not have two different users on two websites is it?